# How can I extract English characters from a string of mixed (Arabic and English) Letters

Tags: python, selenium

I have many strings similar as below

```
"A ali - عالي"
"Baghdad - بغداد"
```

I want to extract  "A ali", "Baghdad" out of this using python but not splitting based on "-".

Please help.

Comment: yes, If you have a string in a variable then start traversing in a string and based on the ASCII value you can get what you want

Comment: You need to put all the examples that you want this code to handle. You can't put a couple here and then put more counter examples after someone has answered your question. You are causing extra work for people that are trying to help you.

Comment: Where are your code attempts at this?

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """A ali - عالي
Baghdad - بغداد"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r"([A-Za-z\s]+)", line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
A ali 
Baghdad
```

Comment: Thanks,  But what about if I want to exclude only arabic charcters

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: For example in 

s = "A ali - عالي
Sétif
Baghdad - بغداد
Ras al-Khaimah "

Now I want the result to include:-

"A ali
Sétif
Baghdad
Ras al-Khaimah"

Now, the challenge is that "Sétif" is not an English word and not an Arabic word also.  and Ras al-Khaimah inlcudes hyphen in between name.